# Sharing handlebars templates between server and client with browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, browserify

Goal: I don't want to have to duplicate templates, partials, and helpers for handlebars. I want to re-use them in the client and on the server.

Problem: When registering helpers on the client side, it doesn't work.

Stack: Node.js (with express), handlebars.js, browserify

NPM modules being used: `browserify-handlebars`, `express-handlebars`

In my **client** side I have the following file:

```
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');

Handlebars.registerHelper('json', function(obj) {
    return JSON.stringify(obj);
  });

var aTemplateFunction = require('../../templates/blah.handlebars');


var html = aTemplateFunction({
  someObject: {
    'key': 'value'
  }
});
```

I have browserify running on it to compile the template.

`../../templates/blah.handlebars` is:

```
{{ json someObject }}
```

It will compile the template fine, but it won't apply the helper properly. The error I get is:

`Uncaught Error: Missing helper: 'json'`

What am I doing wrong here?

Additional question: I found this example (http://codyrushing.com/using-handlebars-helpers-on-both-client-and-server/) about sharing helpers between the client and server, but it seems like more of a hack to me.

What's the proper way to share helpers between the client and server?

Comment: Cody Rushing's approach looks like a great solution to me. The only other approach I can think of -- and I'm not suggesting this -- would be to set up a little file watching utility that copies content from a shared _helpers.js_ file and embeds it at some predefined point in both a server-side module and a client-side script.

Comment: I'm a little confused by his article to be honest. Since he is precompiling his templates (with grunt I guess?) I don't know exactly how he is doing that and how he's tying it  together.

Comment: @TroyGizzi my implementation is here: http://pastie.org/9643533 but I'm getting `object is not a function` on `register(Handlebars);` within the client.

Comment: The only part of that JavaScript that you'd need client-side is the self-invoking function (everything from `(function () {` down to `})();`). Here's a JSFiddle that works, using just that (plus a few lines below it to actually render the template output): http://jsfiddle.net/troygizzi/nk71svog/

Comment: As for how it ties in server-side, look for this comment in Cody's article: _same file that gets used on our client_ -- the `helpers.js` file would contain just the self-invoking function and nothing else; it would be referenced as an external script both on the client and on the server.

Comment: @vini I ended up moving to use jade because it gave me less headache. Now I'm experimenting with swig and browserify and pre-compiling the templates although the current support for this is minimal.